# Scrapy Splash got detected by Trivago

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, headless-browser, splash-js-render

When I use Splash to scrape Trivago, I got Captcha. It doesn't happen if I use curl or using a normal Scrapy request.

Is there a way to use Splash but not get detected as a bot by Trivago?

Comment: Try chaning the user agent string that Splash sends to the server. See [`splash:set_user_agent`](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-set-user-agent) in the documentation.

Comment: it doesn't work. Still got detected.

Comment: Do you get some valid responses first and then start getting blocked? How fast are you crawling? Be polite and lower down the speed.

Comment: I tried to render the page myself using Splash console and didn't get any captcha. Probably you were scraping it in a way that got you marked as a robot. Either use a proxy or maybe you can try to solve the captcha programatically. What kind of captcha is it?